# Nested function pointers or function composition

Tags: c, math, function-pointers, function-composition

I am working on C implementations of calculus operations (such as derivatives, integrals, etc...). As an example, here's the template definition of my `derivative` function:

```
double derivative(double (*f)(double), double x);
```

Let's say I want to compute the derivative of `exp` at 1, the call would then be: `derivative(exp, 1);`

Pretty basic stuff. Now my question is, how would I go about (if it is even possible) to pass a composition to my `derivative` function? I tried passing `exp(cos)` which got me

`error: passing 'double (double)' to parameter of incompatible type 'double'`.

How would I do it? Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How does it make sense to pass the `cos` function to the `exp` function? Can you give an example of the actual equations you want this to solve?

Comment: @Lundin what I would like to be able to do is to compute the derivative of any composition (`exp(cos(x))` was just an example, `ln(sqrt(x))` is another)

Comment: In that case, the correct solution is to call the functions in sequence. It probably doesn't make much sense to implement such equations using generic programming.

Comment: One might be forgiven to think C is the wrong language here? What is feasible is not always what is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some sort of run-time control over the composition, you could write a function that evaluates an array of function pointers as a composition:

```
// calls functions in reverse order
double compose(size_t n, double (* const fc[])(double), double x)
{
    while (n--)
    {
        x = fc[n](x);
    }
    return x;
}
```

This could be called from another version of your derivative function:

```
double derivative_composed(size_t n, double (* const fc[])(double), double x)
{
    // Example implementation for illustrative purpose only.
    double fx, fxh, h;
    h = x / 1e10;
    if (h == 0)
    {
        h = 1e-10;
    }
    fx = compose(n, fc, x);
    fxh = compose(n, fc, x + h);
    return (fxh - fx) / h;
}
```

To avoid repeated code, your original `derivative` function could be changed to be a wrapper that calls `derivative_composed` with a single function:

```
double derivative(double (* const f), double x)
{
    return derivative_composed(1, &f, x);
}
```

Example usage:

```
int main(void)
{
    double (* const fc[2])(double) = { exp, cos };
    double x = 1.0;
    double xprime = derivative_composed(2, fc, x);
    printf("x = %f, xprime = %f\n", x, xprime);
}
```

Output:

```
x = 1.000000, xprime = -1.444407
```

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the only "practical" way to go about doing what I intend to. Thanks for the answer and code sample!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking for this:

```c
double composition(double x) {
   return exp(cos(x));
}

derivative(composition, 1);
```

Many languages allow you to do something like the following, but C doesn't have anon functions:

```js
derivative(x => exp(cos(x)), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

C does not have any operation for function composition. To compute the derivative of exp∘cos, you can define a function `expcos`:

```
double expcos(double x) 
{
    return exp(cos(x));
}
```

and take the derivative of that.

For a more general solution, you could modify your derivative routine to take both a function pointer and a `const void *` to forward to the function. The function would take the `const void *` as a parameter, convert it to a pointer to a `const` structure of a type particular to that function, and take data from that structure. Then function composition can be implemented with a `compose` function that uses a structure containing two function pointers. However, it would mean you would need to use proxy routines for ordinary functions like `exp` and `cos` that accept but ignore the `const void *`.